# Where can I find types Typescript Types for Tanstack Table library. Looks like official documentation does not have it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tanstack

Cannot find types for the Tanstack Table library

I tried to find it in official documentation - but the only time Typescript is mentioned there is just - the library greatly works with typescript. But no types are explained

Comment: The types are embedded in the npm package. There is an index.d.ts file. Your IDE should handle it.  The tanstack site has docs that describe the usage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.